# How Azure IoT hub registers the new device

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

Can the Azure IoT hub identify the spoofing of identity during the registration process

Assume a new IoT device is joining the IoT hub which is showing the spoofed MAC id to the IoT hub.

Will the Azure IoT hub detect that the device uses spoofed identity.

Answer (score 1):

The Azure IoT Hub Identity Registry is what manages devices identities. You can read some literature about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-identity-registry).

When it comes to authenticating devices, IoT Hub offers several options that are detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security).

In a nutshell you have 3 ways to provision a device with unique identity and credentials: using a connection string with a unique ID and Key (which allows to compute a SAS Token on the device), using a SAS Token (which you would have to create offline), or using an X-509 certificate.

The only way a device could try and spoof an identity would be if someone was able to retrieve these unique id and credentials from a legit device or some other source, reason why we strongly recommend leveraging secure storage solutions on the device to not allow for the device credentials to be stolen and reused.

If a device tries to connect using valid credentials already used by another device, then the first device will be disconnected, but beyond this, you can (and it is recommended) to implement some security strategy such as rolling secure keys regularly. These strategies depend on your scenario, device type, the way you plan to provision the devices... IoT Hub gives you the tools to implement what fits your needs.

Comment: If the new device comes for registration without any certificate then how to authenticate it.

Comment: We just announced the upcoming Azure IoT Device Provisionning Service that will allow "zero-touch provisioning" for devices. The new service will be available soon. In the meantime, you need to provision the device your own way and if the device has no valid credentials, he won't be authenticated.